# QGIS does not get installed on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-10

A few weeks ago I formatted my laptop where among other things QGIS 3.4 was installed.

In the last 48 hours I was busy trying to reinstall it, but until now without succeess.
I have a Thinkpad with Windows 10 PRO. I installed versions 3.4 and 3.2 several times: everything goes well but I do not get the launch icon and in "ProgramFiles" the *postinstall.bat* icon gives the message:

> *Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item*.

With a Windows technician I have checked all the admin settings in my PC. We also have created an administrative account. Same issue.

Edit: 
I have installed using OSGEO4W. It was installed not only QGIS 3.10 but also a lot of software which I would like to get rid of. When I open QGIS I ge this message: ' An error has occurred while executing Python code:

> *PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithmProvider.py", line 86, in loadAlgorithms
>       version = SagaUtils.getInstalledVersion(True)
>     File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaUtils.py", line 141, in getInstalledVersion
>       universal_newlines=True,
>     File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: You do not have permissions to the file or the file location., check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2669244/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-when-you

Comment: This was checked by the Windows Technician, seems to be in the right place.

Comment: Did you use an administrator type account when you installed QGIS?

Comment: Yes my account is administrator.

Answer (score 1):

- Check your antivirus. In my knowledge, Kaspersky has already classified QGIS as a Trojan in the past on our network when using the Osgeo4W installer.
- Try the .exe rather than the Osgeo4W installer if it's the case.

Comment: I do not have antivirus, Windows 10 has some functionality builted in. I have installed until now the -Standalone installers from OSGeo4W packages-

Comment: I have installed using OSGEO4W.

Comment: Have a try with the standalone installer and see if it goes through